# Unable to compile PnetCDF: 'tst_rec_vars' test fails

Tags: c, linux, hdf5, netcdf4

I am trying to install [PnetCDF](https://parallel-netcdf.github.io/) from source. I used the `1.12.2` version for installation. MPICH, Zlib, Szip, HDF5 and NetCDF-4 have been installed from source successfully (HDF5 and NetCDF-4 have been built with parallel I/O support).

**MPICH** is installed as follows (v3.4.2):

```
./configure --prefix=${DIR}/mpich --with-device=ch4:ofi CFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" --enable-fortran
make
make check
make install
export PATH=${DIR}/mpich/bin:${PATH}
```

Where `DIR` is the root directory all the libraries are installed to (with their own directory).

**Zlib** (v1.2.11):

```
./configure --prefix=${DIR}/grib2
make
make check
make install
export CPPFLAGS="-I${DIR}/grib2/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L${DIR}/grib2/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DIR}/grib2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

**Szip** (v2.1.1):

```
./configure --prefix=${DIR}/szip
CC=mpicc
make
make check
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DIR}/szip/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CPPFLAGS="-I${DIR}/szip/include ${CPPFLAGS}"
export LDFLAGS="-L${DIR}/szip/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
```

**HDF5** (v1.8.22):

```
export HDF5=${DIR}/hdf5
./configure --prefix=${HDF5} --with-szlib=${DIR}/szip --with-zlib=${DIR}/grib2 --enable-parallel CC=mpicc --enable-fortran FC=mpifort
make
make check
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${HDF5}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CPPFLAGS="-I${HDF5}/include ${CPPFLAGS}"
export LDFLAGS="-L${HDF5}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
export PATH="${HDF5}/bin:${PATH}"
```

**NetCDF4-C** (v4.8.0):

```
./configure --prefix=${DIR}/netcdf --disable-dap --enable-parallel-tests --enable-large-file-tests --disable-extreme-numbers CC=mpicc
make
make check
make install
export PATH="${NETCDF}/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${NETCDF}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export CPPFLAGS="-I${NETCDF}/include ${CPPFLAGS}"
export LDFLAGS="-L${NETCDF}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
export LIBS="$(nc-config --libs) ${LIBS}"
```

**NetCDF4-Fortran** (v4.5.3):

```
./configure --prefix=${NETCDF} --enable-large-file-tests --enable-parallel-tests CC=${DIR}/mpich/bin/mpicc FC=mpifort F77=mpif77
make
make check
make install
```

The HDF5 configuration shown by `h5pcc -showconfig` is given below (only the part I think relevant is included):

```
Features:
---------
Parallel HDF5: yes
High-level library: yes
Build HDF5 Tests: yes
Build HDF5 Tools: yes
Threadsafety: no
Default API mapping: v18
With deprecated public symbols: yes
I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib),szip(encoder)
MPE:
Direct VFD: no
(Read-Only) S3 VFD: no
(Read-Only) HDFS VFD: no
dmalloc: no
Clear file buffers before write: yes
Using memory checker: no
Function stack tracing: no
Strict file format checks: no
Optimization instrumentation: no
```

And the output of `nc-config --all`:

```
--cc            -> /media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/mpich/bin/mpicc
--cflags        -> -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/include -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/hdf5/include -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/szip/include -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/grib2/include
--libs          -> -L/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/lib -lnetcdf
--static        -> -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -ldl -lz -lcurl
--has-c++       -> no
--cxx           ->
--has-c++4      -> no
--cxx4          ->
--has-fortran   -> yes
--fc            -> mpifort
--fflags        -> -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/include -I/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/include
--flibs         -> -L/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/lib -lnetcdff
--has-f90       ->
--has-f03       -> yes
--has-dap       -> no
--has-dap2      -> no
--has-dap4      -> no
--has-nc2       -> yes
--has-nc4       -> yes
--has-hdf5      -> yes
--has-hdf4      -> no
--has-logging   -> no
--has-pnetcdf   -> no
--has-szlib     -> yes
--has-cdf5      -> yes
--has-parallel4 -> yes
--has-parallel  -> yes
--has-nczarr    -> no
--prefix        -> /media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf
--includedir    -> /media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/include
--libdir        -> /media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/netcdf/lib
--version       -> netCDF 4.8.0
```

So far, so good. Everything was installed without any failure. All `make check`s have been passed.
The trouble arises when I try to compile PnetCDF from source. I tried PnetCDF version 1.11.2 for installation (in fact, I triedd several older versions as well, more on that later). The installation is attempted as following:

```
./configure --prefix=${DIR}/pnetcdf --enable-large-single-req --enable-netcdf4 --enable-shared=yes --with-netcdf4="${DIR}/netcdf" MPICC=mpicc MPIF77=mpif77 MPIF90=mpif90 MPICC=mpicc MPIF77=mpif77 MPIF90=mpif90
make
make tests
make check
make ptest
make ptests
```

But, it fails at `make ptest`. The failed test is `tst_rec_vars.c` and the error message is:

> Error at line 78 of tst_rec_vars.c: expect dim X len 4 but got 3
> Error at line 78 of tst_rec_vars.c: expect dim X len 4 but got 3 fail with 2 mismatches
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:1354: ptest4] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/source/pnetcdf-1.12.2/test/nc4'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:780: ptests] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/case/work/hwrf/libraries/source/pnetcdf-1.12.2/test'
> make: *** [Makefile:965: ptests] Error 1

Heres the test that is failing (GitHub link): [tst_rec_vars.c](https://github.com/Parallel-NetCDF/PnetCDF/blob/27efebe0547b4b62a7ee714ba9917f9e7544ca3d/test/nc4/tst_rec_vars.c)

It seems that the test is checking a NetCDF file for the lenth of dimension in it. I assume the NetCDF file it is checking is `tst_rec_vars.nc`. The output of `ncdump -h` on this file is given below:

```
netcdf tst_rec_vars {
dimensions:
        X = UNLIMITED ; // (4 currently)
variables:
        int U(X) ;
        int V(X) ;
}
```

That is, the NetCDF file's `X` dimension indeed has a length 4, although the test program beleives it is only 3. But, if I were to run the test manually as `./tst_rec_vars`, it runs correctly.

> *** TESTING C   tst_rec_vars for record variables to NetCDF4 file ------ pass

Could it be due to parallel processing/threading? The test in question is run under a section titled `test/nc4: Parallel testing on 4 MPI processes`. I assume the NetCDF file was tested before it was formed completely, which could explain why I got a length 1 `X` dimension in the NetCDF file from `ncdump` at one point.

```
>>>ncdump -h tst_rec_vars.nc
netcdf tst_rec_vars {
dimensions:
        X = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
variables:
        int U(X) ;
        int V(X) ;
}
```

What exactly is going on here? How do I fix it?

Edit:
I'm trying to install it on CentOS 7, since I was encountering the above mentioned issue, I tried to install it on a Debian 11 system. But I am getting the very exact error in both systems.

Comment: Debian example: `apt install libpnetcdf-dev pnetcdf-bin`. ... And you can read how it was built, Debian 11 https://packages.debian.org/source/bullseye/pnetcdf → → http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pnetcdf/pnetcdf_1.12.2-1.debian.tar.xz → the file `rules`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I can't install it from the repository, I need to build it from the source. As for the Debian package you've linked to, I checked the `rules` file, but I don't think I understood anything. Could you to elaborate on what I should be looking for in it?

Comment: Please edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68892920/edit your question to include OS name and version. .... Then I may have some ideas.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I first tried it on CentOS 7, and then on a Debian 11 install. But both systems are encountering the same error.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to verify that you're actually using of all the custom-built tools and libraries, both at build time and at run time, as opposed to using the system's versions of one or more of those.  You're installing them in locations that are outside all the normal search paths, so the tests might need help finding them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have used various flags during the compilation process to make sure the proper tools and libraries used. It can be verified at least for HDF5 and NetCDF, from the output of `h5pcc -showall` and `nc-config --all`.
The specific test that fails does not fail when run manually, doesn't that mean the libraries are configured correctly? Is there a way to verify that all tools/libraries are compiled with the intended dependencies?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Would checking the output of `./configure` be enough to verify?

Comment: No, @RogUE, it would not.  `configure`'s output speaks only to the checks that that script performs.  If it provides output that allows you to distinguish what version of a given library it locates, then that *probably* indicates which will actually be used by the build.  For shared libraries, however, which library is used at runtime is a separate question.  The `ldd` utility can help you probe that, but you must take care, because its behavior, like that of the dynamic linker itself, as affected by environment variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.